# Selenium throws "Element No Longer Valid" after WaitForElement

Tags: c#, asp.net, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Here's a strange one. I'm using Selenium WebDriver with IE11 and a C# testcase I'm writing.

```
      driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("testpage.aspx");
      WaitUtility.WaitForElement(By.Id("HEADER_ID"));    //Waits for element to be present
      var element = Driver.FindElement(By.Id("HEADER_ID"));  //fetches the element
      Assert.IsTrue(element.Displayed); //verifies that the element is present
```

Weirdly enough, the above code will successfully run the WaitForElement command (which should mean that the element is present) but the element.Display method will return false.

So Selenium Waits for an element to be present Before continuing only to then throw an error saying that the error doesn't exist.

--

*Extra info:
Sometimes the testcase will execute without a problem. 
Sometimes, it'll return "element no longer valid / Stale Element Reference Exception which I've researched here on StackOverflow but no example seems to apply to my situation as this exception is usually thrown when a DOM object has been recreated with the same defining attributes, but in my case, the object is successfully located with the WaitForElement-method and I can't imagine that my element has been recreated or unattached to the DOM before the next method "element.Displayed" is called.*

```
Selenium version: x64 Selenium InternetExplorerDriver 2.42.0
OS: Windows 7
Browser: Internet Explorer 11
Browser version: 11.0.9600
```

Comment: "I can't imagine that my element has been recreated or unattached to the DOM before the next method "element.Displayed" is called", are you 100% positive about this ?

Comment: How could I verify? I figured since there's not much than a millisecond between the execution of the two commands.

Comment: I found a solution to this with a try catch statement and recursive function. A while statement might work too.
1. Create WebDriverWait wait
2. element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists....)
3. use try statement - try to use the element
4. in catch, call the containing function and return

This unconditionally works for me, even though it is ugly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough rep to comment - and I'm afraid this isn't an answer/solution.

But ... I think I have run into a similar thing. I wait until an element exists, and then try and click on/use the same element. If it gets past the wait, that would imply that element is there, but then the click fails. Nothing else on the page has changed. But I'm using the remotewebdriver and Python bindings with Chrome and FireFox. Both the remote machine (a Ubuntu VM) and my local machine (W7Pro) are 64 bit.

When I searched for similar examples, I found this:

[Python Selenium WebDriverWait and Click inconsistently giving StaleElementReferenceException()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22237020/python-selenium-webdriverwait-and-click-inconsistently-giving-staleelementrefere)

... which is the same symptoms. Still using Python. But not using the remote driver.

So the problem *seems* to be the same in all three instances. Although the setups are all slightly different.

I never did find a solution. Neither did the guy in the link above as far as I can tell.

So I'm intrigued to see if you get anywhere with it!

Comment: Yes, I saw that post but well, obviously it was no help. Thanks for your input though.

Comment: In most cases, people seem to end up writing helper functions which encapsulate things like this in try/catch type exception handling to make it more robust. Wait/Find > Assert/Assign > Click/Use > Repeat {x} times until it works or give up elegantly. Mind you, I've had to do things like this with most test automation software. The built in methods are seldom robust enough on their own ...

Comment: I've added a waitForElement present in my default click method, with a try catch for this exception. However, it doesn't solve my problem, which btw, seems to occur only some of the times, suggesting that maybe some scripting might be the cause of it.

Comment: Even after putting sufficiant syncup points, am getting the same issue in IE and c# webdriver when I try to iterate the webtable. Any solution has been found for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Having success with Actions interactions to get around this problem:
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;

Actions action = new Actions(driver);
      action.MoveToElement(xrmBrowser.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[contains(text(),'Contacts')]"))).Click().Build().Perform();